# Unable to play video in IE 11

Tags: video, internet-explorer, html, mp4

When I try to access a mp4 video url in IE 11 it prompts the user to download the video instead of playing it in the browser. But I am able to play the video in Chrome/Firefox. Here is a sample url,
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4

Is it because IE 11 does not have any in-built Media Player. How to make the video stream in IE 11 instead of prompting the user to download. Kindly help. I am using Windows 10 and IE 11.471.17134.0. Thanks!